# Main Menu Key C++

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating a simple C++ console program for fun and I am looking for a way to allow a user to return to a “Main Menu” output at any time if they were to hit a function key like F1 or F2.

Is there anyway I can have my program be at the ready to accept this key at any time or do I need to have a switch statement that can call the “Main Menu” print function everytime the program accepts user input? Is this something that is perhaps out of reach for a console-based program?

EDIT: For now, I am only working on a Windows-based program.

Comment: Are you trying to have it instantly detect the keypress (like <F1> is pressed and the menu appears immediately) or would it be ok for the user to press a key and then hit enter?

Comment: A portable way to do this in c++ could possibly be using the `ncurses` library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Thanks for the suggestion! I have always liked the idea of using ncurses, although I think as of now a Windows port of ncurses hasn’t made it very far? :(

Comment: @blackbrandt I am looking to have it instantly detect the keypress

Comment: @darwin80 _ncurses_ works well with windows terminals of course. The portability is all of it's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows:

You can use GetKeyState or GetAsyncKeyState, but that won't give you keydown/keyup events. It will only tell you what keys are currently down.

So if you need to get the keydown/keyup events, you could install a hook. A Console window has a window handle that is owned by code in Windows and a message pump, also owned by code in Windows.

You can get the window handle of of the console window by using GetConsoleWindowThen install a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook using SetWindowsHookEx to listen in on messages send to the console window.

You might try a WH_MSGFILTER hook instead. I don't know if this works for console windows, but it would generate less messages to be ignored if it does work.

Comment: This answer assumes OP is on Windows, which is not specified in the original question.

Comment: That won't work on systems other than windows. Is there some evidence in the OP regarding this?

Comment: @jjo The usual course of action is to ask the OP about clarification in comments before answering. It's easy enough to get enough reputation to comment on questions.

Comment: @jjo Thanks for the reply, I will try to test this method out as soon as I can!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this user is <50 rep, though. So commenting is not a thing they can do yet.

Comment: @Chipster And what? I mentioned that it's easy enough to get rep for being able to comment.

Comment: how would you like me to get the rep?